# unable to link to fftw3 library

Tags: c, linker, linker-errors, fftw

I am compiling a test program to test the fftw3 (ver3.3.4). Since it is not installed with root previlidge the command I used is:

```
gcc -lm -L/home/my_name/opt/fftw-3.3.4/lib/ -I/home/my_name/opt/fftw-3.3.4/include/ fftwtest.c
```

where the library is installed in

```
/home/my_name/opt/fftw-3.3.4/
```

My code is the 1st tutorial on fftw3's website:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fftw3.h>
int main(){
    int n = 10;
    fftw_complex *in, *out;
    fftw_plan p;

    in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(n*sizeof(fftw_complex));
    out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(n*sizeof(fftw_complex));
    p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(n, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_execute(p); /* repeat as needed */

    fftw_destroy_plan(p);

    fftw_free(in); fftw_free(out);

    return 0;
}
```

when I compiled the program it returns me following errors:

```
/tmp/ccFsDL1n.o: In function `main':
fftwtest.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `fftw_malloc'
fftwtest.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `fftw_malloc'
fftwtest.c:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `fftw_plan_dft_1d'
fftwtest.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `fftw_execute'
fftwtest.c:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `fftw_destroy_plan'
fftwtest.c:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `fftw_free'
fftwtest.c:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `fftw_free'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

A quick search implies that I am not linking to the library correctly, but interestingly it does not complain about the declaration of fftw_plan and fftw_complex. In fact if I remove all functions starting with "fftw_", keeping only the declaration, it will pass the compilation.

So where did I go wrong? Is the linking correct? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have told the linker where to find the library through `-L`, but you haven't told it which library to link to. The latter you do by adding `-lfftw3` at the end of the line, before `-lm`.

Additionally, the `-L` flag needs to be listed after `fftwtest.c`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also add that you link to the fftw library.

Add something like:

```
-lfftw
```

It depends on what the library file is actually called. (Note how you do that for the math library with `-lm`.)